# How to reverse order of cell text seperated by "/" in Excel/Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

As you can see in the image below, I have a column with values like this:

10/1/1399

11/1/1399

23/2/1400

16/12/1390

1/1/1400

and I want to re-order them to be like this:

1399/1/10

1399/1/11

1400/2/23

1390/12/16

1400/1/1

[Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxIKA.png)

is there a way to do that either on MS Excel or Google Sheet?

Comment: Check on here, there are a couple of helpful posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(QUERY(SPLIT(A1:A,"/"),"select Col3, Col2, Col1"),LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN("/",1,row))))
```

Comment: For Excel or Googlesheets?

Comment: Tried it on Google Sheet

Comment: @SolarMike, this is a GSheets solution.

Comment: Should state that, or expect people to be miffed when it does not work in Excel...

Comment: to be fair, Excel has so many different versions that even if I were to provide an Excel formula, it's not guaranteed to work for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Within sheets, you can also try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A2:A6),"(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","$3/$2/$1"))
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input is actual text, representing a date, two options that worked for me in GS:

[image]

Formula in `B1`, results may be locale settings dependent:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(DATEVALUE(QUERY(A:A,"Where A is not null")),"yyyy/m/d"))
```

Formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(A:A,"Where A is not null"),"(\d+)(\/\d+\/)(\d+)","$3$2$1"))
```

---

For Excel, the 1st option won't work because it's a date prior to 1-1-1900 (AFAIK). What could work is:

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A:A,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("/",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"/"),{3,2,1}))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel:

```
=BYROW(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN("/",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(r,"/"),{3,2,1}))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, alternatively, may I suggest `=MAP(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),LAMBDA(....` in case of a header =)

Comment: That's good, I hadn't seen that use of tocol with the second parameter to remove blanks.

Comment: BTW the timings for both versions seem to be about the same - running it on a full column is much slower as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the most efficient way would be to make a macro that does this as a one column operation, but the easiest way I could think to do it is to separate the cell into columns delimited by the slash, and then concatenate them in reverse order and add the slashes back.